# Roscore and Sensors node are not starting on boot [Clearpath Husky]

Tags: ros, clearpath, husky, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have recently got a husky from clearpath. When I boot the system the general behavior was to launch all the rosnodes on boot. I added my own laser scanner, and wanted to add it to the upstart menu. I used the [robot_upstart](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart) package. But after adding my laser scanner launch file. On the next boot none of the nodes are starting. Is there a way to fix this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302019/roscore-and-sensors-node-are-not-starting-on-boot-%5Bclearpath-husky%5D/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2018-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I removed all the job from `/lib/systemd/systemd` by using rosrun
`robot_upstart uninstall job_name`
and then augmented all the launch file to one master job file using:

```
 rosrun robot_upstart install my_custom_package/launch --job job_name --augment
```

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2018-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0